# Displaying rendered layers in 3D Maps in QGIS 3.8.x with variable transparency/opacity

Tags: qgis, 3d, qgis2threejs, transparency-opacity

I am looking at using QGIS to help facilitate conversations/do some thinking in 3D.

I have tried both QGis2threejs and the native 3D Map available in QGIS 3.x and both have their strengths.

The native 3D map is able to work better with complicated 3D shapefiles for buildings, as well as fairly quickly render large maps. However, QGIS 3.x does not include transparency for layers. Where I work we have protected views that impact on building height - viewing them in 3D without transparency/variable opacity only tells half a story (the image below shows these views in 3D as brown planes)

Qgis2threejs is able to render transparency but doesn't work as well with some of my other shapefiles. Ideally I'd like to use both - but at the moment transparency is key.

Is there a way to include transparency/variable opacity in QGIS 3.x 3D Maps?

I am running QGIS 3.8.2 (I also have 3.4.1 installed). I can't always upgrade to latest versions as I work within a large organisation - one where I am possibly the only QGIS user!

[image: 3D map transparency comparison between QGIS 3D Map native and QGis2threejs]